# Convert Javascript Date object to Excel serial date number

Tags: javascript, excel, datetime, datetime-format

So I have a Javascript date object with year, month, days, hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds data and I need to convert this object to an Excel serial number but I didn't find a way to do that.
I found how to convert only a Date object but the way I found didn't consider the time part.

Any suggestions?
Thank you,
Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by "excel serial number"? Can you share an example?

Comment: From memory, it's an integer number of days since 1 Jan 1900 with a decimal part for the time. Note that for dates prior to 1900, the integer part goes backwards but the time part goes forwards, noon on 31 Dec 1899 is -1.5 (so minus one day, plus 0.5 day in time), not -0.5.

Comment: [*Converting date JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66333838/converting-date-javascript) might be useful, as well as [*Serial Number and Serial Date in Excel*](https://www.lifewire.com/serial-number-serial-date-3123991).

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200980/excel-convert-javascript-unix-timestamp-to-date/54153878#54153878

Answer (score 13, accepted):

finally I was able to convert it properly, I used the following code to do so:

```
let date = new Date();
let converted = 25569.0 + ((date.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Where 25569 is the difference between Excel start date (1900/01/01) and Javascript start date (1970/01/01).

Thank you all.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

```
function ExcelDateToJSDate(serial) {
   var utc_days  = Math.floor(serial - 25569);
   var utc_value = utc_days * 86400;                                        
   var date_info = new Date(utc_value * 1000);

   var fractional_day = serial - Math.floor(serial) + 0.0000001;

   var total_seconds = Math.floor(86400 * fractional_day);

   var seconds = total_seconds % 60;

   total_seconds -= seconds;

   var hours = Math.floor(total_seconds / (60 * 60));
   var minutes = Math.floor(total_seconds / 60) % 60;

   return new Date(date_info.getFullYear(), date_info.getMonth(), date_info.getDate(), hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

Or you can use:

```
function SerialDateToJSDate(serialDate) {
  var days = Math.floor(serialDate);
  var hours = Math.floor((serialDate % 1) * 24);
  var minutes = Math.floor((((serialDate % 1) * 24) - hours) * 60)
  return new Date(Date.UTC(0, 0, serialDate, hours-17, minutes));
}
```

Comment: The question is to convert a Date into a excel serial number. You are doing the other way around ...

Comment: This is still converting a serial date to a JS date. The question is asking about the opposite direction, ie convert a JS Date in to a serial number. And do you mind to explain where that `hours - 17` is coming from?